# How to check whether System.Net.WebClient::DownloadFile succeded?

Tags: powershell

I am downloading a file, and want to know whether it was downloaded properly. If I use an invalid filename, it still downloads a 2KB file, without displaying any error. `$?` is `True`.

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( $url, $destfile)
```

So even checking whether the file exist locally does not say whether the download succeeded.

Comment: Arguing semantics. Your webserver must be serving a HTTP 200 or 300 response for a filename which doesn't exist, presumably a redirect to the homepage or something. After that, the PowerShell code works fine - you ask for it to download from a URL, it does so, you ask it to save to a file, it does so, as far as everything it can tell, the download you asked for worked fine, so `$?` is `True`. @vitalygolub's answer shows if the server returns 404 for missing files then PS will throw an error - but if the server says the URL is OK, how can PS read your mind and tell that's not what you wanted?

Comment: I do not expect from PS to read my mind. The webserver was not configured by me.

Comment: Then what it indicates the download isn't right, more specifically than "I wanted something else"? Do you have a file hash of the file you expected? Do you know what kind of file you expected so you can check that it has, e.g. PDF or ZIP headers? Do you know how big it should be? Is the 2Kb fake content always the same page that you can check the content? Can you test with `Invoke-WebRequest -Method HEAD` and look for the status code of a 30x redirect? How do *you* decide the file is wrong?

Comment: I am working on a script and if I download it manually it is not 2KB. It is so simple.

Comment: `(Get-Item -Path $destfile).Length -ne 2Kb` then?

Comment: It would work if Windows always creates in such cases a 2KB file by default. But I do not know Windows enough to be sure.

Comment: but it's nothing to do with windows, it saves whatever the webserver sends. Open the file in a text editor, it will be HTML of a homepage or file not found page most likely.

Answer (score 1):

this statement throws an exception, try to catch, this code works fine for me

```
try { (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://www.google.com/test","test") }catch {echo $_.Exception }
```